# Can I auto-complete by tab in zsh with regular expression

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I use oh-my-zsh configuration. When I want to auto-complete, I need to first type correctly the initial letter. For example
`go`, then <kbd>tab</kbd> will give `google-chrome`. If I type `*le-ch*`. It didn't work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that behavior by setting the [completion style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-completion-system_002c-styles) [`completer`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-completer_002c-completion-style) to include the [`_expand`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fexpand) control function. This is what I use:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _match _prefix
```